# reducer only returns the last object

Tags: javascript, object, reducers

I have an object like this one,

```
 var myObj = {
        'id001':{ a:'a', b:'b', c:'c', d:'d', e:'e', f:'f', g:'g', h:'h', i:'i'},
        'id002':{ a:'a', b:'b', c:'c', d:'d', e:'e', f:'f', g:'g', h:'h', i:'i'},
        'id003':{ a:'a', b:'b', c:'c', d:'d', e:'e', f:'f', g:'g', h:'h', i:'i'},
        'j':'j'
    };
```

the object may contain many keys like: `'id001', 'id002', 'id003','id004',` ... etc and it only will have a single key `'j'`, and I want to pass this object to a reducer like that:

```
var newObj = Object.keys(myObj).reduce((c, v) => {
    if (typeof myObj[v] === 'object') c = Object.assign(c, { id: v }, myObj[v]);
    else c[v] = myObj[v];
    return c;
}, {});
```

that returns me an object like this:

```
{id: "id001", a: "a", b: "b", c: "c", d: "d", e:"e", f:"f", g:"g", h:"h", i:"i", j:"j"}
```

the problem is that this reducer only returns me the last object, and I would like it to return an object like this:

```
[

{id: "id001", a: "a", b: "b", c: "c", d: "d", e:"e", f:"f", g:"g", h:"h", i:"i", j:"j"},
{id: "id002", a: "a", b: "b", c: "c", d: "d", e:"e", f:"f", g:"g", h:"h", i:"i", j:"j"},
{id: "id003", a: "a", b: "b", c: "c", d: "d", e:"e", f:"f", g:"g", h:"h", i:"i", j:"j"}

]
```

can someone please help me?!

Comment: Your expected output is invalid.

Comment: @HassanImam I've just fixed it

Comment: If you want to reduce to an array, your accumulator would want to start as one..  and then you will want some array.push..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to create an array and push all the object with its key whose key contains string `id`. Then iterate through the generated array and add all the key which don't have `id` key.

```js
var myObj = { 'id001':{ a:'a', b:'b', c:'c', d:'d', e:'e', f:'f', g:'g', h:'h', i:'i'}, 'id002':{ a:'a', b:'b', c:'c', d:'d', e:'e', f:'f', g:'g', h:'h', i:'i'}, 'id003':{ a:'a', b:'b', c:'c', d:'d', e:'e', f:'f', g:'g', h:'h', i:'i'}, 'j':'j' },
    result = Object.keys(myObj).reduce((r,id) =>{
      if(id.includes('id')){
        r.push({id, ...myObj[id]});
      }
      return r;
    },[]);
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(k => {
  if(!k.includes('id')){
    result.forEach(o => o[k] = k);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```